# Set Date Boundaries on Date Picker Fragment

Tags: android, datepicker, android-fragments

I've got a very simple date picker fragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Activity a = getActivity();

        Button dateDueButton = (Button) a.findViewById(R.id.dateDue);
        String sYear = Integer.toString(year).substring(2, 4);
        String sMonth = Integer.toString(month + 1);
        String sDay = Integer.toString(day);
        dateDueButton.setText(sMonth + "/" + sDay + "/" + sYear);
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to set a "date boundary". For example, if the current day was Feb. 9th, I would like only dates from Feb. 10 or later to be shown on the fragment. How can I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`minDate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29) and [`maxDate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29) parameters in the [`DatePicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) class.

Notice that these are API level 11 classes, so you'll have to implement this functionality yourself for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

You will get Datepicker object from DatepickerDialog by using this method **getDatePicker()**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
    OnDateSetListener {
   private DatePickerDialog datepic;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    datepic=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    return datepic;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    Activity a = getActivity();

    Button dateDueButton = (Button) a.findViewById(R.id.dateDue);
    String sYear = Integer.toString(year).substring(2, 4);
    String sMonth = Integer.toString(month + 1);
    String sDay = Integer.toString(day);
    dateDueButton.setText(sMonth + "/" + sDay + "/" + sYear);
}

public void setMinimumDate(Calendar mintime){
   datepic.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mintime.getTimeInMillis());
}
public void setMaximumDate(Calendar maxtime){
   datepic.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxtime.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

> Use public methods setMinimumDate and setMaximumDate to set boundaries

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can take the current system date and compare it with the date selected by the user. If, the user selected date is less than the current date then you can set boundary on the date. Else, you can proceed with your savings.The give code snippets may help you,

```
    public static long getTimeDiffInDays(String birthday) {
    int beforeLenght = birthday.length();
    int afterLenght = birthday.replace("/", "").length();
    int checkFormat = beforeLenght - afterLenght;
    String newBirthday;
    if (checkFormat == 2) {
        int lastIndex = birthday.lastIndexOf("/");
        newBirthday = birthday.substring(0, lastIndex).trim();
    } else {
        newBirthday = birthday.trim();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    Date newDate = new Date();
    Date olddate = new Date();
    try {
        newDate = sdf.parse(sdf.format(now.getTime()));
        olddate = sdf.parse(newBirthday);
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long datediff = (olddate.getTime() - newDate.getTime())
            / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

    if (datediff < 0)
        return datediff + 365;
    else
        return datediff;
}
```